# cp command syntax difficulty

Tags: command-line, cp

I have rescued many files from a failing hard disk. They are in 500 sub directories each containing 500 files.

I am trying to copy all the files in all the folders into new subject directories (like jpg, mp3 etc)

Inside the top level directory (MikeO) I am using the following command:

```
cp -R * /test1
```

where test1 has already been created under MikeO

This just recreates the entire sub-directory structure and all the files in test1

```
cp -R *.jpg /test1 results in:
cp: cannot stat ‘*.jpg’: No such file or directory
```

can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

There are no files named "*.jpg" in the location where you issued the command. You need to take that literal: "*.jpg" is NOT "*.JPG" or "*.jPg" or any other combination. Windows is different in that way: it will see those as the same.

In the same directory do an `ls` and it will show contents of that directory. `ls *jpg` to list all files ending on `*.jpg`.

Mind that -R means recursive BUT that applies to directories only when copy-ing. It does not mean it will get you all files in all directories that have a file ending in `*.jpg`.

If you want to find all files ending in *.jpg and copy them over to /test1/ this will work:

```
find . -depth -name '*.jpg' -print | cpio -pmdv /test1/
```

Add a `~` to /test1/ if it is in your home directory.

> where test1 has already been created under MikeO

What do you mean with this? If you meand "MikeO" home directory: the `/` starts at `/` (ie. root). If you meand `/home/MikeO/test`/ you need a `~` in front of the `/test1`.

Comment: cpio: cannot make directory `/test1': Permission denied
cpio: /test1//./recup_dir.1/recup_dir.140/f14847120.jpg: Function open failed: No such file or directory
^C
tony@tony-HP-620:/media/tony/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/MikeO$ ^C

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind.  I liked your complex code - but it doesn't work even when executed with "sudo" in front.  Your other comment about .jpg I understand. FYI MikeO is a directory on an external USB hdd

Comment: @TonyC that 1st one: test with sudo. might be permissions problem if you do not own the disk ;)

Comment: I can now get the first part of your code snippet to work. Up to the -print statement I get all the jpg files listed on the screen. Where it falls over is in the cpio command. I checked the syntax which looks fine but as soon as I execute the full command, I get:
cpio: cannot make directory `/test1': Permission denied
cpio: /test1//./recup_dir.375/f73577640.jpg: Function open failed: No such file or directory

Comment: I do own the disk and /test1 exists!

Comment: @TonyC normally I'd get what the problem is with this but I am stumped :-D

Comment: Many thanks for your advice. I also tried the rsync solution proposed and then ran out of disk space because there is about 150Gb of data and my laptop didn't have enough space! Anyway I will recreate a smaller data sample and try again tomorrow.  I'll let you know!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rsync` instead of `cp` command to copy particular extension files. 
Following is command for copying only .jpg extension files.

```
rsync -pavr                                                 \
    --include '+ */' --include '*.jpg' --exclude '- *'      \
    /path/to/source/directory  /path/to/destination/directory
```